# i have a list of elements and i want to remove the specific duplicate elements and append it at beginning of the existing list in Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
>>> l1
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0]
```

output expected is as below

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

i have tried myself as below but looking for solution without using l2 list as shown in my example

```
for i in l1:
    if i==0:
        l1.remove(0)
        l2.append(i)

>>> l1[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8,9]
>>>l2[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Final output

```
>>> l2+l1
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: i..uh..uhm.. do you mean sort?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code!

Comment: its not sorting .. i just picked 1 element and that need to be appended in the beginning..

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]
def nonzero(a):
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x: x != 0)
print (nonzero(l1))
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

solution with for loop:

```
l1 = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,8,9,0]

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if(l1[i] == 0):
         l1 = [l1[i]] + l1[:i] + l1[i+1:]
print (l1)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```